# Writing dataframe to Excel takes extremely long

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have got an excel file from work which I amended using pandas. It has 735719 rows × 31 columns, I made the changes necessary and allocated them to a new dataframe. Now I need to have this dataframe in an Excel format. I have checked to see that in jupyter notebooks the `ont_dub` works and it shows a dataframe. So I use the following code `ont_dub.to_excel("ont_dub 2019.xlsx")` which I always use.

However normally this would only take a few seconds, but now it has been 40 minutes and it is still calculating. Sidenote I am working in a onedrive folder from work, but that hasn't caused issues before. Hopefully someone can see the problem.

Comment: That is a massive Excel file. You're abusing Excel with that much data. Consider an alternate format.

Comment: The problem is I have to upload this data into Microsoft Dynamics Nav, which uses Excel templates to upload data. So unfortunately I cannot escape Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, if you want to save such high amount of datas in a local folder. You don't utilize excel. If I am not mistaken excel has a know limit of displayable cells and it wasnt built to display and query such massive amounts of data (you can use pandas for that). You can either utilize feather files (a known quick save alternative). Or csv files, which are built for this sole purpose.

Comment: The problem is I have to upload this data into Microsoft Dynamics Nav, which uses Excel templates to upload data. So unfortunately I cannot escape Excel.

Comment: Are you sure, about that? If you are trying to analyze large datasets, I wouldn't recommend a tool that can only intake specific amounts of data.

Comment: Well I do the analyzing not in Excel, but I used pandas. However now I have to put those changes into an Excel file.

Comment: How about you save it in csv, run the to_csv() command and them. Exchange your file format in your pc

Comment: That is a good idea, I'll give that a shot!